# Electric field due to an infinite plane slab

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

So the solution says that in the x z plane, E = 0 by symmetry
that is my problem, how is E = 0, maybe I can't visualize it correctly, however if I assume that that's really the case, I can continue the rest of the problem easily by using a cylindrical gaussian surface penetrating through the planes which are perpendicular to lines y = d and y = -d
So my question is, why are the rest of the electric fields zero? Is it because we're trying to figure out the electric field as a function of y and so we're counting the other planes out? Or am I misunderstanding some kind of symmetry?

Comment: *'Introduction to Electrodynamics'* David J. Griffiths, Third Edition 1999, **Problem 2.17** page 75.

Answer (score 1):

Place the end caps of your cylindrical Gaussian surface at y = + h and – h.  Then evaluate the emerging flux as h approaches zero. The field in the xz plane is zero because you have equal quantities of charge on each side.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/317471)

Comment: This does answer the question as to why E is zero in the xz plane.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the the electric field is not zero in xz plane somewhere far from the origin. That would mean that the infinite plane symmetry is broken and the field "senses" the edge of the plane. In other words, every point on the xz plane is not distinguishable for a infinite plane, so in xz plane the E field should be the same and zero.

If that symmetry argument still doesn't makes sense, maybe try a following calculation. Find a field of a uniformly charged rod. Close to the the surface of rod and it's middle the field will have a negligible component parallel to the rod. However, as you approach the edge of it, the field start rotating to more parallel.

Comment: Is there a diagram to describe it?

Comment: I can try drawing one, but the one that you have in the original question is pretty much it. Let me know what exactly is confusing in my answer, so I can try clarifying it.

Comment: What is the electric field due to the plane perpendicular to y=d cancelling out with to produce a zero field?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the electric field had a component in the $\hat{x}$ direction.  Now rotate the slab 90 degrees about $\hat{y}$. Now the field has a component in the $\hat{z}$ direction.

But how can that be?  The entire universe of this problem is symmetric with respect to rotations about $\hat{y}$.  Rotating about $\hat{y}$ by any amount produces a situation that is indistinguishable from the starting position.  If there is a field component in the $\hat{x}$ direction, I *can* distinguish the starting position from a rotated one.

The only way to respect the symmetry of the problem and to make the positions indistinguishable is to have $E_x=E_z=0$ .